# Kendo grouped-listview

Tags: kendo-mobile

I would like to know how to modify the example grouped listview that comes with kendo mobile.
The list view shows both flat view and grouped view.  How do you make the items in the list view clickable so they will navigate to a different web page when clicked?

I've tried creating a template with an anchor tag and href and it works in IE but does nothing when clicked on the android phone.

```
//The Template

<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="myclass">
        <a href="TenantView.html">#:name#</a>
    </div>
</script>


//The data binding

function mobileListViewDataBindInitGrouped() {
        $("#grouped-listview").kendoMobileListView({
            dataSource: kendo.data.DataSource.create({ data: groupedData, group: "letter" }),
            template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
            fixedHeaders: true
        });
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You should not test your kendo code on IE. Always use a Webkit based browser like Chrome or Safari to test your code as on the mobile device, the app will be running using Webkit.

Comment: I've tested using both chrome and standard android browser on my phone. nothing happens when I click the links even though they are valid .  Thanks

Comment: Can u post you views complete code? In which event r u calling this function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some trial and error I have found that if i remove the **div** tag in the template, the anchor tags work correctly.  Not sure if this is a bug or by design.
Thanks Whizkid747 for your help.

```
//Updated Template (removed <div>)
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
   <a href="TenantView.html">#:name#</a>
</script>
```

Comment: interesting... actually u can have any html element inside the template.. I would suggest you report this to Kendo team

Comment: @Downvoters Please explain the downvote and give me a better answer.